# Floating Scroll Bars

Tags: osx, scroll-bars

In Mac OS X Lion and above, scroll bars can "float" on top of the content and only appear when scrolling. This provides insight on where you are in a document as well as the size of the document, without the scroll bar taking up room.

Emacs by default does not respect this system setting. For the Emacs GUI, is there any way to enable this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as far as I know. I think that one of the Emacs OS X developers mentioned that it would require quite a substantial change in the way Emacs handle the layout of a frame. However, all that is needed is a well-motivated developer -- any takers?